# Possible to deactivate parts of Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate without reinstall?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate installed. It includes a lot of features that I rarely use, mostly around Team Explorer and Architecture and Modeling Tools. These things have a ton of commands and menus and context menu items that really clutter my display and probably slow down VS launching etc.

*Is it possible to deactivate these components without uninstalling Ultimate and installing Pro instead?* I do use these components on rare occasions and don't want them completely gone, just temporarily disabled.

I looked at the installer's "change" options, and it only has high level options like "C#" and "Visual Basic", nothing about the modeling tools. These components also do not show up in the addins or extensions lists.

(I'm fine with a hacky solution, like renaming a folder or editing an XML file.)

Comment: I've found that removing menu items is a bad idea. In the past I have found VS crashing on startup for some reason, only to discover that some add-in that overwrite a built-in feature with its own menu caused a crash. Had to restore menus from defaults to repair. Sometimes it is safe, sometimes not. I believe it was something TFS related that crashed if its menu items did not exist..may have been database commands though. Can't remember.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adam Driscoll to the rescue.

http://csharpening.net/?p=640

He wrote a tool called [VSTweaker](http://csharpening.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/VSTweaker.zip) that does exactly this.